# Авторизация средствами AuthorizationService

Tags: java, android

коллеги! Опишу кратко ситуацию (приготовтесь к тяжелому материалу):
Есть приложение с авторизацией через сайт, средствами вот этой библиотеки [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) (так хочет заказчик). Так же он хочет два приложения в одном проекте (разделение выполнено через *productFlavors*). Проблема в том, что данные об авторизации сохраняются где-то в куках (или еще где - этого я как раз понять не могу). Если я авторизируюсь в П1, и открою П2, то после отправки запроса на сайт об авторизации, мне не будет показан экран с вводом пароля и логина (показывается он средствами бразуера смартфона). Экран пропущен, я буду считаться как уже авторизированные (ведь так оно и есть, но в П1, а не в П2 и в этом будет ошибка). Как заставить браузер забыть о том, что я авторизирован при захочет с другого приложения? (очистить куки, или еще какую магию знает кто)

Ниже я приведу участки кода:

Вызов экрана авторизации:

```
public void startLogin() {
    AuthorizationServiceConfiguration serviceConfig =
            new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
                    Uri.parse(AUTH_ENDPOINT), // authorization endpoint
                    Uri.parse(TOKEN_ENDPOINT)); // token endpoint

    AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            serviceConfig,
            CLIENT_ID,
            ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
            Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_login_callback_uri))
    ).setScope(APIConfig.SCOPE);
    AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();
    Intent authIntent = authorizationService.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(request);
    startActivityForResult(authIntent, AUTH_REQUEST_KEY);
}
```

Перехват результата от браузера:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != AUTH_REQUEST_KEY || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        //LOGOUT_REQUEST_KEY is called when leaving logout webview
        //if logout webview is cancelled or back button is closed, result value is 0
        resetViewState();
        return;
    }

    AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(data);
    AuthorizationException error = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(data);

    if (response == null) {
        handleLoginError(getString(R.string.login_screen_error_login_cancelled));
        return;
    }

    final AuthState authState = new AuthState(response, error);

    authorizationService.performTokenRequest(response.createTokenExchangeRequest(), (tokenResponse, exception) -> {

        if (exception != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Token Exchange failed", exception);
            exception.printStackTrace();
            handleLoginError(getString(R.string.login_screen_error_token_request_failed));
            return;
            //handleLoginError(exception.getMessage());
        }

        if (tokenResponse != null) {
            authState.update(tokenResponse, null);
            if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR_role.equalsIgnoreCase("manager")) {
                if (authState.getAccessToken() != null) {
                    JWT jwt = new JWT(authState.getAccessToken());
                    Claim manager = jwt.getClaim("role");
                    List<String> roles = manager.asList(String.class);
                    boolean isManager = roles.contains("manager") || roles.contains("\"manager\"");
                    if (!isManager) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Access denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        binding.setIsLoading(false);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            AuthStateHelper.saveAuthState(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    authState.getAccessToken(),
                    authState.getIdToken(),
                    authState.getRefreshToken());

            showHomepage();
            return;
            /*
            Log.i(TAG,"Auth state: "+authStateString);
            String authStateString = authState.jsonSerializeString();
            Log.i(TAG,
                    String.format("Token Response [ Access Token: %s, ID Token: %s , Refresh Token: %s]",
                            tokenResponse.accessToken, tokenResponse.idToken, tokenResponse.refreshToken));*/

        }

        handleLoginError(getString(R.string.login_screen_error_token_request_failed));
    });
}
```

---

Сохранение токенов (и прочей прихоядщей информации о авторизации) я сохраняю в shared Preference. там я тоже реализовал раздельное хранение, но неожиданно это не помогло. В связи с этим, я предположил, что сохранение данных происходит в самом бразуре или сервере (но скорее всего браузере). Если приложение удалить, и установить заново - то придется вводить пользовательские данные. Если разлогиниться, то выкенет на экран авторизации в обоих приложениях.

**ПРАВКА:**
applicationId Для обоих приложений разный:

```
flavorDimensions 'env', 'role'
productFlavors {
    daily {
        dimension 'role'
        applicationId = "com.xxx.aaa"
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    manager {
        dimension 'role'
        applicationId = "com.xxx.aaa.manager"
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules-manager.pro'
    }
    dev {
        dimension 'env'
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.xxx.aaa.dev'
        ]
    }
    live {
        dimension 'env'
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.xxx.aaa'
        ]
    }
}
```

А так же привожу AuthStateHelper:

```
public class AuthStateHelper {

public static void saveAuthState(Context context,
                                 String accessToken,
                                 String idToken,
                                 String refreshToken) {
    String IVString = null;
    String encryptedRefreshToken = null;
    String newAuthStateString = null;

    EncryptionHandler handler = new EncryptionHandler(context);
    byte[] IV = handler.generateIV();
    IVString = Base64.encodeToString(IV, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    encryptedRefreshToken = new EncryptionHandler(context).encryptValue(IV, refreshToken);
    //newAuthStateString = AuthStateHelper.removeRefreshToken(authState.jsonSerializeString());

    //SharedPrefsUtils.saveAuthState(context, newAuthStateString);
    SharedPrefsUtils.saveIV(context, IVString);
    SharedPrefsUtils.saveRefreshToken(context, encryptedRefreshToken);
    SharedPrefsUtils.saveIdToken(context, idToken);
    SharedPrefsUtils.saveAccessToken(context, accessToken);
}

/**
 * Load saved auth state and add refresh token to auth state after decrypting it
 *
 * @param context Context
 * @return Auth state
 */

public static String getRefreshToken(Context context) {

    String IV = SharedPrefsUtils.getIV(context);
    String encryptedRefreshToken = SharedPrefsUtils.getRefreshToken(context);

    EncryptionHandler handler = new EncryptionHandler(context);
    return handler.decryptValue(encryptedRefreshToken, IV);
}
}
```

**ПРАВКА № 2**
Продебажил авторизацию, с целью изучения токенов. Использовал https://jwt.io/ . Получилось, что ответ возвращаемый сервером содержит одни поля. Ниже привожу accessToken cо слегка измененными. Для обоих приложений токены одинаковые, за исключение двух первых полей. Я увидел там несколько видов id, но как их настриоть?)

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я уже говорил, *SharedPrefsUtils* разделены для обоих приложений. Надеюсь, вы сможете еще что-то мне посоветовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без наличия AuthStateHelper предположу, что оба приложения подписаны одним ключом, поэтому читают одни и те же настройки - старый токен из другого приложения.

Выложите helper, build.gradle (меняете или нет applicationId и т.д.)

Comment: хорошо, завтра с работы добавлю файлы. Возможно у обоих приложений сейчас один ключ используется, т.к. второе только-только начали разрабатывать, оно по-сути отпочковалось от первого.

Comment: Сергей, я добавил часть gradle и AuthStateHelper. При генерации apk файл используется 1 ключ на двоих, но разве это может повлият?

Comment: Могу ошибаться но sharedPreferences у нас шарятся между одним пользователем uid, а он выделяется на каждый ключ, соответственно шарится. Попробуйте залогировать что выдает  getRefreshToken у приложений и увидите верно ли это. Если загружает сохраненный токен, попробуйте в ключ добавлять BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Comment: хорошо) пока задачу отодвинули как не приоритетную. sharedPreferences  я разделил между приложениями (ключи вынес в интерфейсы: один для клиента, другой для менеджера). Но я чувствую, что где-то в ваших словах есть конечный ответ) Отмечу ваш ответ как правильный, но если что, надеюсь вы мне в комментариях потом поможете)